# cannot find a module express

Tags: node.js, express

waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~/nodedbtest$  npm install express
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ugin-import":"2.18.2"'

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/waseem/.npm/_logs/2020-01-28T07_47_56_274Z-debug.log
waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~/nodedbtest$ npm install express@4.17.1
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ugin-import":"2.18.2"'
```

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/waseem/.npm/_logs/2020-01-28T07_48_26_728Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache before installing the module in this case.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then,

```
npm i express
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install express@latest
```